# Looking for a GUI Extension example using the SearchView?

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

There is some information on Blogs and SDL LiveContent about creating GUI Extensions.

What I am looking for is an example of an extension which uses the SearchView results screen.

I want to create a button which calls the Tridion search (perhaps twice) with a custom search pattern, aggregate the results and display it in the SearchView results screen. Inspecting this SearchView in Chrome shows that it is a div with id FilteredItemsList.

Any thoughts or suggestions are welcome...

Comment: Couldn't you just use a virtual folder for this?

Comment: A VirtualFolder contains the result of a fixed search query. I need a more flexible search with a custom search pattern provided by the editor.

Comment: After visiting a Virtual Folder, the editor could adjust the saved search and even re-save the updated search to the Virtual Folder. What are you thinking in terms of flexible and custom search patterns?